# Why am I getting blank pdf pages when I try to reproduce examples on asymptote's site?

Tags: asymptote

I'm still new to asymptote but so far I've read the documentation and I believe to have followed the directions accordingly. I've checked that all the packages are installed and the necessary gsviewer and I'm on MikTex 2.9

What I tried to do was to reproduce this drawing:

by using this command on cmd

```
asy -V -f -pdf example



import graph3;
import grid3;
import palette;

currentprojection=orthographic(0.8,1,1);

size(400,300,IgnoreAspect);

defaultrender.merge=true;

real f(pair z) {return cos(2*pi*z.x)*sin(2*pi*z.y);}

surface s=surface(f,(-1/2,-1/2),(1/2,1/2),50,Spline);
draw(s,mean(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow())),black);
grid3(XYZgrid);
```

However I only managed to get a blank page in the resulting pdf for the first example as shown below:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

and for this animation

the command I used was:

```
asy -V -f -pdf example_02
```

for the asy file as described below

```
// Embed a movie to be run in an external window.

import external;

// External movies require the pdflatex engine.
settings.tex="pdflatex";

// Generated needed mpeg file if it doesn't already exist.
asy("mp4","wheel");

// Produce a pdf file.
settings.outformat="pdf";

// External movie: viewable even with the Linux version of acroread.
label(embed("wheel.mp4"),(0,0),N);
label(link("wheel.mp4"),(0,0),S);

which is a wheel moving.

but I only obtained this error. 

C:\Users\Flor\Mis documentos>asy -V -f -pdf example_02
error: could not load module 'wheel'
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

(example_02_.tex ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifluatex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\color.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg"))
(example_02_.aux) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base\supp-pdf.mkii"

[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\grfext.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))
(example_02_.out) (example_02_.out)

LaTeX Warning: File `wheel.pdf' not found on input line 59.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `wheel.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.59 ...n:wheel.mp4}{\includegraphics{wheel.pdf}}}
                                                  %
[1{C:/Users/Flor/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(example_02_.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.
9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/t
ype1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt12.pfb>
Output written on example_02_.pdf (1 page, 14403 bytes).
Transcript written on example_02_.log.
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9/asymptote/plain_shipout.asy: 87.10: runtime: shipout
 failed

C:\Users\Flor\Mis documentos>
```

Why is that happening? I must note that I'm on Windows 7.

Could it be that what I'm doing is just plain wrong?. I hope somebody can help me with this issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I do not get an empty page. However, in my case the application freezes. (This may not help you but maybe others who are collecting data in order to solve the problem.)

Comment: @marmot thanks for the welcome. If you don't get an empty page, then what's the problem from my side?. Could it be that the software is wrong? Did I installed a wrong distribution or package?. I'm still dumbfounded by all of this. It shouldn't be complicated. But it is a relief that the error I am getting seems not to be unique.

Comment: @marmot `asy` option `-V` opens the OpenGL viewer. This might be the reason for the app freezing in your case. Remove it for file-only output.

Answer (score 3):

## First example

You specified PDF as output format

```
asy -f pdf input.asy
```

**(You put a  "`-`" in front of `pdf` which is wrong.)**

By default, if the output format is PDF, 3D graphs are embedded into PDF as interactive 3D object (that can be rotated, zoomed, panned using the mouse). This requires Acrobat (Reader) as a PDF viewer.

If you just want a static PDF image, run Asymptote as

```
 asy -f pdf -noprc -noV input.asy
```

PRC is the file format of the embedded 3D object and is only supported by Acrobat. As @Charles suggested in the comments, on Windows it may be necessary to add option `-noV`. It suppresses the OpenGL viewer and ensures writing the output files and exiting `asy` in a regular fashion.

## Second example

Your second example depends on `wheel.pdf` which is a multipage PDF with animation frames. You have to generate it before compiling `example_02.asy`.

For getting `wheel.pdf`, run `asy -f pdf` on [wheel.asy](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/animations/wheel.asy):

```
asy -f pdf  wheel.asy
```

Compiling `example_02.asy`,

```
asy -f pdf example_02.asy
```

makes an MP4 video from  `wheel.pdf` and then produces a PDF (`example_02.pdf`) showing the first frame of `wheel.pdf`. Also, a link to the external MP4 is inserted. On click (in the PDF viewer of your choice) the video is started in an external video player.

Comment: I'm currently trying out your suggestion. So far I've removed the - from the code but it does not resolve the issue of obtaining a blank pdf page. **However** if I do click and allow the 3D it does show the object which you mentioned that allows rotation, as you mentioned I only made it to work with Adobe which is odd because it should work with any other viewer. Although it is not resolved the animation issue. Why am I obtaining those errors?

Comment: But `-noprc` generates a standalone PDF with the object rendered as a bitmap (for me, at least.)

Comment: You say that the resulting PRC file is only supported by Acrobat but how about of obtaining a file which is readable by any pdf viewer?. Is there a windows command to do so?. How about the animation why did I obtained so many errors and couldn't obtain a mp4 file and a static pdf file?.

Comment: As I said, `-noprc` produces a bitmap rendering of the 3D scene in the output PDF. This PDF works in any PDF viewer.

Comment: If compiling is necessary how do I compile that file?. I tried copying it to MikTex but it is displaying errors. Do I need to use other program for that?

Comment: I wrote all the necessary commands in my answer.

Comment: I am unable to produce a static image of the first example. The only displayed result is the 3D object. If I do execute that command (for the first example) a window is displayed showing the object for rotation but the pdf is not opened and the program on cmd is left running. I have to end the process to open the pdf file separately. For the second example I'm getting an error which says that asymptote stopped from working and program closed thus unable to execute properly.

Comment: I am working with TeXLive on Linux. Without `asy` option `-V` the OpenGL viewer is not started and I get the PDF output file. Maybe it is a MikTeX issue you are faced with.

Comment: It is strange because by going with the latter link you provided I obtain a readable pdf file which is recognized by foxit reader in different pages and displays the wheel in different frames. So it looks that I obtained this right, but the second part doesn't produce a mp4 file. Looking at the cmd I obtain this error    C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9/asymptote/animation.asy: 85.15: merge failed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88781/discussion-between-alexg-and-chris-steinbeck-bell).

Comment: On Windows the `-V` option is assumed. Try `-noV`.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: Thank you for this suggestion! I forwarded it to OP in the chat.